# PHP Guzzle: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server – What could be the reason?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, guzzle, mamp-pro

I use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to make a proxy request like this:

`Frontend (Vue/Axios) -> proxy.php -> REST API`

I need the proxy to include Basic auth headers to get access to the REST API (of kirby cms), and I don't want to include the credentials in my frontend of course.

This worked fine until I started to use multiple promises (4 simultaneous requests to 4 different endpoints).
Now I restart my local MAMP pro server, then I can execute the requests **once**, and they work.
Everytime I reload the page after the first time, I don't get anything back in axios, because obviously my server does not return anything:

> [02-Mar-2020 22:18:17 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /Users/USER/Documents/github/folder/raz/cms/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:200
>   Stack trace:
>
> # 0 /Users/USER/Documents/github/folder/raz/cms/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(155): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
>
> #1 /Users/USER/Documents/github/folder/raz/cms/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(105): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
>
> #2 /Users/USER/Documents/github/folder/raz/cms/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory))
>
> #3 /Users/USER/Documents/githu in /Users/USER/Documents/github/folder/raz/cms/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 200

My **first question** is: What could be the reason for the server not to return anything?
Is it some memory that is used up? And restarting resets things? (My php 7.2 memory limit is at 128MB)
Any other idea?

My **second question**: What could I do to solve this issue?

Thank you for any hints!
I am not super experienced with PHP and server stuff, so maybe I am just missing out on some easy stuff...

Cheers and thanks in advance.

PS:I am aware that thjere are other posts with the same title, but the solutions there did not help me out...

------ UDPATE -----

I wanted to see what happens if I don't make the axios calls to the proxy simultaneously but staggered.
I always await one call to be finished before I start the next one.
This takes it's time, but eventually returns all 4 responses.

If I wait for all 4 responses to be returned I can reload the page and do the whole process again. If I start reloading let's say after 2 requests (request 3 & 4 are still pendent) my PHP server crashes and I start getting the error above.

So **question 3** would be:
How can I make sure that all requests are cancelled?
And why is this causing my server to stop?

Comment: You should check the logs on the PHP side.

Comment: Well that are those... I opened the `php_error.log` which is the output file of MAMP. And in there I see the errors above...